# Incoming string don't have the correct format c#

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to create a query:

```
 MessageBox.Show(id_order+"-"+ row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "-"+ row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "-"+ row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "-"+ row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            string query = "INSERT INTO \"ORDER_DETAIL\"(id_order, id_product, quantity, val_siva, iva) VALUES(" + int.Parse(id_order) + "," + int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + "," + int.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + "," + int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()) + "," + int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()) + ") ";
```

The MessageBox, show me that all the values are correct, for example: 13-3-1-700.00-0. But the second line has the problem that i can not understand.

Comment: 700.00 is not an int.

Comment: You should not use 'int.Parse' when you're building a string.

Comment: It's bad practice to build SQL strings like this. You should use parameters for user inputs.

Comment: You might try building the string in parts instead of in one pass, so you can see where the error occurs. Like everywhere you concatenate something, try doing that on a new line, doing something like `query = query + somethingNewHere;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to build the query (assumes Sql Server; for other databases, just the correct ADO.Net provider objects, ie OleDBConnection instead of SqlConnection). I don't think this will fix all of the problems — it's not likely all of the columns are integers — but this will begin to fix the issue in the question and put you on a *much* better path forward.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}",
       id_order, row.Cells[0].Value, row.Cells[2].Value,  row.Cells[3].Value, row.Cells[4].Value));

string query = "INSERT INTO \"ORDER_DETAIL\" (id_order, id_product, quantity, val_siva, iva) VALUES( @id_order, @id_product, @quantity, @val_siva, @iva);";

using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(id_order);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_product", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val_siva", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@iva", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```